# How to store webpage?

Tags: html, github-pages

I want to save the following webpage (https://cs231n.github.io/) such that I can easily view it offline. Is there a way to do this without copying each page by hand?

I already downloaded some software but they are not working properly.

I see that there is a GitHub repository, can this be used to offline view the content of the page?

Comment: About what software you writing about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use third party program as [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/). Your linked web-site is relatively simple and this program should handle it.

The hardest yet most correct way is to, yes, [clone](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) web-site from git repository and serve it on your local computer. It can be not easy depending on how site is built, does it use database and so on.

Comment: HTTrack worked. I reinstalled it. It seems I had a later version which was not working hence I thought the program was not working. Thank you for the quick response :).